# queuing theory - how to find the distribution of number of clients in G/D/1/n queue?

Tags: probability-distributions, queueing-theory

I'm having a trouble with analyzing G/D/1/n queue. 
Queue definition:
Customers arrivals -  the time between arrivals is uniformly distributed ([y,y+1]) and the service time is constant - x.

How can I calculate the distribution of number of clients in the system (steady state)?

I know that the mean value of the arrivals is y+0.5, but I got a little confused with how it applies to how many customers are arriving and per what time interval.

Comment: I don't believe this is a well-studied problem in the literature. You may be best off simulating the process to compute a point estimate for the stationary distribution.